# Safari won't display the all page (to wild)

Tags: safari, macos, bug, tabs

I noticed that some webpage won't be displayed correctly in Safari since 10.11.
The page are to wild and we can't see the left side (even if trying to scroll right)

Actually its not even the page itself, even if you try to do a search ( CMD + F ) we won't even see the search field.

Answer (score 1):

What I realise its this happen when the tab is pinned.
The resolution I found its to unpin the tab, open a new tab with the same URL and pin the tab again.